# Rails - How do I redirect back to post after a comment error whilst preserving the form data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a basic post / comment setup. Here, I call them pins and replies, but the same format applies, respectively.

My replies (comments) are nested under pins (posts). When I submit a reply with an error I redirect back to the pin, but any data entered on the form is lost. I'd like to preserve this.

**replies_controller.rb**

```
def create

    @pin = Pin.find(params[:pin_id])

    @reply = @pin.replies.build(params[:reply].permit(:reply))
    @reply.user_id = current_user.id
    @reply.save

    if @reply.save
        flash[:success] = "Reply successfully created"
        redirect_to pin_path(@pin)
    else

        if @reply.errors.any?
            flash[:warning] = "#{@reply.errors.count} Problems found: #{@reply.errors.full_messages.to_sentence}"
        end

        redirect_to pin_path(@pin)

    end

end
```

Because it does a redirect, I think this is what is wiping the form. How can I handle the error so that it renders the view of the pin (post) I just came from, instead of redirecting?

Thanks a heap!
Michael.

Answer (score 2):

Do not redirect, instead:

`render 'pins/new'`

Comment: Doing this renders the wrong action. I am trying to render the view of the pin I was just replying to. So, for example, I'm making a reply on /pins/5 and I need to get back there, showing the reply errors.

Answer (score 0):

Use `render` instead of `redirect`

```
def create
  @pin = Pin.find(params[:pin_id])

  @reply = @pin.replies.build(params[:reply].permit(:reply))
  @reply.user_id = current_user.id
  @reply.save

  if @reply.save
    flash[:success] = "Reply successfully created"
    redirect_to pin_path(@pin)
  else
    if @reply.errors.any?
      flash[:warning] = "#{@reply.errors.count} Problems found: #{@reply.errors.full_messages.to_sentence}"
    end
    render :template => "pins/show"
  end
end
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It's not the new action in reply I want to show. This reply is being made on a pin. It needs to render the pin I was just trying to reply on.

Comment: Rendering the show template gives me: Missing template /show with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Is it looking for show in reply? Because I need to render the show of the pin I was just viewing. For example, I may have been making a reply on /pins/5 and need to get back there!